# Is it possible to isolate COM1 and COM2 on a Garmin G1000?

Tags: radio-communications, avionics, g1000

Is it possible to isolate COM1 to one pilot and COM2 to the other pilot?

When I'm getting the ATIS it's hard to listen to both COM channels sometimes depending on the amount of traffic.

I used to be able to do this on an older aircraft I flew, and loved the feature in a crew environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Garmin_G1000_Diamond_DA-42.jpg))

On the audio panel installed between the two G1000s, there should be a COM 1/2 key. That will enable the split COM operation with COM1 going to the pilot and COM2 going to the copilot.  What avionics are in the aircraft that you have?

> Split COM allows the pilot to use COM1 while the copilot uses COM2. This proves very helpful for talking to an FSS en route without leaving the ARTCC frequency. Pressing the COM 1/2 key on the audio panel turns on Split COM mode ([Garmin](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/G1000:Non-AirframeSpecific_PilotsTrainingGuide_InstructorsReference-04_.pdf)).

Comment: I've tried that button, it doesn't seem to work, I'll try it again tomorrow.  My company probably didn't pay for that feature to work.. :P

Comment: Interestingly enough, the G1000 Cessna NAV III manual (page 98-99 at http://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/190-00498-07_0A_Web.pdf mentions that the COM1/2 button is not used in the NAV III aircraft.  Which is weird because I thought I had used it... maybe I'm misremembering.  What A/C are you using the G1000 in?

Comment: I'm using it in the Cessna Grand Caravan

Answer (score 2):

Different Aircraft manufacturers actually integrate the modular G1000 hardware and software into their aircraft. In doing so, each manufacturer has a large amount of control as to what features are actually enabled on their avionics in any particular type or airframe. An example of this is the Cirrus Perspective package which is basically a customized G1000 or the Cessna Nav III package used in Cessna 172S’s.

A good example of an aircraft manufacturer  customization related to what you are mentioning is Cessna’s disabling of the split com (COM 1/2) function, COM 3/COM 3 MIC, PA, TEL, and several other buttons in the Cessna 172S Nav III. You can find an online POH to review this info - the POH describes which functions are disabled.

Bottom line: each aircraft manufacturer gets to pick what works in both hardware and software to a certain degree even though the G1000 hardware and base software is the same.

Comment: @Brad I thought my answer was pretty complete for your question!

Comment: Cessna seems to have disabled it on the Grand Caravan...